# Other database synchronization tools besides Microsoft Synchronization Framework?

Tags: sql-server, database, synchronization

We have been using Microsoft Synchronization Framework for syncing up disconnnected laptops with a master SQL Server. Unluckily it has been an issue to correctly get all the dependencies installed and we also get weird errors sometimes.

Are there any other commercial or open source alternatives that people have used that are easier and more robust?

Comment: You'll have better luck on serverfault.com than here

Answer (score 1):

[Redgate](http://www.red-gate.com) is known for having a very good database sync tool. There are others as well, but Redgate is often the most recommended tool set that I've seen and it works very well.